# Flutter widget test - wait Future completion

Tags: flutter

I have a widget test in flutter that pumps the widget under test,
and when it opens, performs a background operation (staticWrapper.requestPermission()) which returns a Future and, based on its result, set a state.
The problem is that the test is not waiting this future to complete, test code:

```
/// When micro permission denied, should show error message.
testWidgets('When micro permission denied, should show error message.',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
  when(staticWrapper.requestPermission(Permission.RecordAudio))
      .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(PermissionStatus.denied));
  await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
  final loginText = find.text(callScreen_microPermissionDenied);
  expect(loginText, findsOneWidget);
});
```

Affected widget code:

```
void _requestMicroPermission() async {
final result =
    await staticWrapper.requestPermission(Permission.RecordAudio);
debugPrint("Microphone permission status: $result");
if (result == PermissionStatus.authorized) {
  native.init();
} else {
  setState(() {
    _loginText = tnsManager.getText(TranslationsManager.callScreen_microPermissionDenied);
  });
}
```

}

The expect() method is called before the setState() call.

Any help?

Comment: you have to call `tester.pump` again when you do a `setState`.

Comment: @RémiRousselet there is no way to do that because the setState is done in the class under test.

Comment: What you did is what I suggested though. You don't need `andSettle`. A simple `pump` is enough

Comment: Sorry @RémiRousselet, I didn't understand you correctly and you're right, pump is enough, I correct my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue using `WidgetTester#pumpAndSettle()`:

```
testWidgets('When micro permission denied, should show error message.',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
  when(staticWrapper.requestPermission(Permission.RecordAudio))
      .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(PermissionStatus.denied));
  await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
  await tester.pump();
  final loginText = find.text(callScreen_microPermissionDenied);
  expect(loginText, findsOneWidget);
});
```